# Updated Android Studio can't run an application

Tags: android-studio

It's showing me the following errors:

```
6:01:42 PM Plugin Error
           Problems found loading plugins:
           Plugin "Google Analytics Uploader" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "NDK WorkspaceManager Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Firebase App Indexing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
           Plugin "Firebase Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.<... (show balloon)
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to File->Settings->Plugins-> here choose the Android Support Plugin. Look for the checkmark in this line. You should set it so that the plugin isn't disabled anymore.
Confirm and it should be done. If not, try to restart Android Studio.